# Search for string in a webpage with frames

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to search the webpage for particular strings, and I am using the following code:

```
strPageContent = appIE.document.documentElement.InnerHTML
```

However, the page is quite complicated and has got a lot of frames and framesets, and the command above returns only the contents of some parents tag. How can I access the contents of the particular div element - please see the code below:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<frameset id="NavContent_Workhorse" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" rows="*,0">
   <frameset id="Nav_Content" border="3" frameborder="1" framespacing="3" cols="240,*">
     <frame name="nav" src="/interface/sidebar/sidebar.def" scrolling="no">
     <frame name="content" src="/interface/home.def" frameborder="1" border="3" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no">
        #document
          <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html lang>
                <head> … </head>
                <body onload="LoadAdd();">
                    <div class="PageTitle" id="PageTitle">...</div>
                    <div class="ToolBar" id="PageBody">...</div>
                    <div id="error" class="none"> … </div>
                    <div id="content" style="display: block; height: 445px;">
                      <form id="frmUSR" method="post" target="workhorse" onsubmit="return false;" action="/setup/users_groups/users/insert.sdl?parentid=14">
                        <div id="wiz_1" class="wiz_vis">
                            <table class="frmTbl">
                                <thead class="title">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="label">
                                            TEXT THAT I AM LOOKING FOR
                                        </th>
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: 
I forgot to add that I did try the code below, but I get a null value

```
Set div = appIE.document.getElementById("wiz_1")
```

Edit 2:

The purpose of the script is to automate filling out the user creation forms on my company's system (webpage UI). I don't know why, but I cannot get a reference to anything that is below the main `<frameset id="Nav_Content" border="3"`. I keep getting null values.

Comment: Please provide a consistent HTML sample that would allow us to reproduce your problem. Is the `<html>` block literally nested in the `<frame>` tag? I was assuming that it's actually loaded from the `src` URL of the frame. Can you open that URL directly?

Comment: Hello, I have updated the HTML Sample - I am trying to get anywhere inside this wiz_1 div (including input fields there) - as for the SRC url - I can open the URL, but it will lead me only to the inactive and empty home page.

Comment: Weird. If this is the actual content of the frameset definition, the nested HTML code should not be active at all. Normally it should only be rendered in browsers that don't support frames. Have you tried inspecting the DOM tree with your browser's web development tools (`F12` in Internet Explorer)?

Comment: OK, I don't really know what have I been doing wrong - however, it appears that I can indeed access the innerText of the elements as you have shown! The problem here is now that I also need to reference the input fields there, and what I get by using `inputfield = div.document.GetElementById("name")` is a STRING that 'says' `Object HTMLInputElement` - however when I try to assign a value to this element by `inputfield.value = "wsed"` I get an Object Required error. Do you know why is that? Thanks a lot for your help Ansgar, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Objects must be assigned to variables using the `Set` keyword: `Set var = object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the content of an element with a particular ID inside a frame like this:

```
Set frame = appIE.Document.parentWindow.window.frames("content")
Set div = frame.document.getElementById("wiz_1")
WScript.Echo div.innerHTML
WScript.Echo div.innerText
```

Comment: I am very sorry, I forgot to write that I did try accessing it by GetElementId, but I always get null. I suppose that the page is being generated dynamically or something. Is there a way to access it in such case?

Comment: @Bartosz Sorry, I had overlooked that your content is inside a frame. Please try again.

Comment: OK, I feel a bit dumb, but I still can't get it to work. I use this code:
`Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4: WScript.Sleep 100: Loop

 msgBox "wait"

 
 Set frame = appIE.Document.parentWindow.window.frames("nav")

 msgBox typename(frame)

 Set div = frame.document.getElementById("wiz_1")` 

and the type of frame is HTMLWindow2, however at DIV I get the error of 'Object doesnt Support this property or Method GetElementById'

Comment: @Bartosz According to the HTML snippet from your question, the tag you're looking for is in the `content` frame, not in the `nav` frame.

Comment: Sorry, my bad for being inconsistent in pasted examples - however I tried both and it doesn't work. Basically, I have no way of referencing anything that is lower than in the `<frameset id="Nav_Content">` - as far as I have googled, it appears that everything else is being generated dynamically and my script calls for it before it is generated. I have updated the question with the purpose of the script - many thanks for help, @Ansgar!